# Is there no way in Windows Defender to exclude a folder from realtime scanning but still include it for scheduled scanning?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, windows-defender

According to the documentation this does not seem possible:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-exclusions-windows-defender-antivirus

Has anyone got any work arounds?

Thunderbird is periodically freezing and I have tracked it down to Windows Defender realtime on my local folders for my IMAP mail in Thunderbird.

Comment: No; The article you linked to is clear.  If you add a folder to the exclusion list.  The folder will not be scanned.

Comment: Can defender be then scheduled via CLI to scan a particular folder only do you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted above, a folder added to the exclusion list will not be scanned.

As a workaround, to have Windows Defender scan a particular folder,
you may use the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -scan -scantype 3 -File path-to-folder
```

If this is always the same folder, you may put the command in a `.bat` file for
quick use.

It is also possible to have Windows Defender scan a folder by the
right-click menu in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to schedule a scan of Windows Defender via the command line which will ignore exclusions, but it will disable all forms of remediation too and will only output the results of the scan to the Terminal that you called it in.

From `& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe' -h`:

```
   -Scan [-ScanType value]
        0  Default, according to your configuration
        1  Quick scan
        2  Full system scan
        3  File and directory custom scan

           [-File <path>]
                Indicates the file or directory  to be scanned, only valid for custom scan.

           [-DisableRemediation]
                This option is valid only for custom scan.
                When specified:
                  - File exclusions are ignored.
                  - Archive files are scanned.
                  - Actions are not applied after detection.
                  - Event log entries are not written after detection.
                  - Detections from the custom scan are not displayed in the user interface.
                  - The console output will show the list of detections from the custom scan.

    . . . continues with other parameters and options . . .
```

I am running my commands from PowerShell but the syntax is more or less the same in Command Prompt (perhaps excluding the `&` at the beginning).

Running a scan with `-DisableRemediation` will ignore file exclusions, but it will also not take any actions, which I suppose is ok.

**Example command:**

`& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe' -Scan -ScanType 3 -File PATH_TO_FOLDER -DisableRemediation`

That should do the trick.